# Send Redis received data to all clients except sender via Socket.IO

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, express

I am making realtime notifications in my Laravel project. I installed NodeJs, Redis server. But I can't find, how to send message from Redis to all socket users, except sender.
So how I do all the stuff (for example, when someone add comment in post:

1. I have confifured all event listeners and other stuff
2. In controller action (CommentsController@store) I call Event::fire(GlobalEventHandler::EVENT, 'User ' . Auth::user()->username . ' just logged in!');
3. GlobalEventHandler connects with Redis and sends message: "User root just logged in!"
4. In server.js (NodeJS server), redis data is processed

So what do I need? - I need to send message to all socket clients, except sender. 
Something like: laravel sends message to redis -> redis and/or socket.io sends data to all users except sender.

My server.js file:

```
const io          = require('socket.io').listen(8080, 'localhost');
const redis       = require('redis');
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

redisClient.subscribe('user.action');

redisClient.on('message', function(channel, data) 
{

    socket.broadcast.emit(channel, data);

});
```

But socket is not defined.. How to correctly get data from Redis and send response to clients? -> EXCEPT sender

Comment: Please change your title to reflect your actual question.

Comment: I hope now the title is correct. :) P.S Sorry about my bad english.

Comment: That's better, it's just to be more specific so we know roughly what your problem is when we scroll through the question list.

Comment: Okay, I'll know that in future! :)